# Hardware specs for Linux machine for cluster administration

Tags: memory, hard-disk, hardware, cpu, software-distribution

I have just started as cluster system administrator and was asked to choose some features to get bought a personal machine to work on, and most intensive calculations will be perform in the cluster. I am a Linux (Ubuntu) user and I do not really know which features I should select at least. Do you know any Linux distribution works better than others for this purpose?

I thought:

- 8+ Cores
- 16/32 GB RAM
- 3 GHz
- Graphics?
- Video?
- Hard disk
- Processor: Intel Xeon, Intel Core...?

I would really appreciate if you have specific considerations to the hardware to tell me.

Comment: Since the calculations are performed on the cluster, what is this machine used for? To administer other computers a Raspberry Pi should be sufficient. What applications are you intending to run? Then check the system requirements of those applications.

Comment: Any desktop computer capable of running your distro of choice will do just fine, based on what you've stated about intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a cluster to do any heavy-lifting that occurs *lowers* the requirements for your personal desktop.

I was a sysadmin for a few small clusters for the phylogenetics group at Dalhousie University for a few years.  All I ever needed on my own desktop was a text editor, terminal emulator+ssh client, and web browser.  One of our clusters came with remote KVM-over-IP which ran a Java applet in a web browser.  That's probably the most compute-intensive thing involved.

If you're developing software to run on the cluster, as well as admin it, you still don't need a lot of cores on your desktop.  If you need to test some MPI code with actual multiple nodes, rather than threads on one machine, you run it on the cluster, not your desktop.

So I'd suggest an Intel i5 with 8GB of RAM, or 16GB if that's cheap enough.  SSD for most filesystems, spinning rust for `/data` if needed.  Depending on what field you work in, you might need more 3D power than you'll find built-in to the GPU on an Intel Skylake.  In that case, NVidia has the best closed-source drivers.  AMD has better open-source drivers, but the open-source drivers are not really good enough.

Xeon or i3 with ECC RAM is not much more expensive, and gives you an extra level of protection from cosmic rays flipping bits.

Comment: Hi Peter, I am working on bioinformatics, too, so my requirements are probably quite similar as yours were. I will mainly write code and run small scripts at the machine, and will probably use a graphics editor such as inkscape. Also, basic functions for mail, web browser, text editor... so maybe AMD is a better option than NVIDIA, if it has better open-source drivers (I've had some problems with the NVIDIA card on my laptop with ubuntu).
Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @PeterPfand: Intel graphics these days are more than capable of all that.  It doesn't look like Inkscape uses OpenGL or OpenCL, so nothing you do benefits from a lot of GPU horsepower.  Intel has the best open-source drivers, because those are the only drivers for Intel.  My AMD 6870 card on open-source drivers doesn't have full power-management working, so it idles at 80W.  I'm running on Intel graphics for the summer.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Very useful answer! And which CPU would you use? More then 2 GHz, more than 3 GHz?

Comment: @PeterPfand: single-threaded performance is really nice.  I'd go for a fast Skylake, like 3.5GHz or faster.  Since you're planning on using the integrated graphics, Broadwell-C (with eDRAM) is also a great choice.  If you need to keep the budget down, a Haswell i5 should be fine, too.  i7 costs more.  Hyperthreading is nice for throughput, but the bump in clock speed is small, and 4 HW threads is enough for most stuff.  The problem with i3 is no turbo, moreso than only 2C/4T, for running a web browser.